# How to pass data to ViewController, using UIViewController

Tags: ios

How to pass data to ViewController using this code?

```
UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *vc = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Catalog"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I want to pass data in example to *itemId*, like here:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

vc.itemId = 0;

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Search the interwebs for `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: You already have the `vc.itemId = 0;` line. What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @Wain I think he means "I want to initialise the presented view controller as if I had done the following...".

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, that I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type cast your `UIViewController` if it's `ViewController`

```
ViewController *vc = (ViewController*)[main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Catalog"];
vc.itemId = 0;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work for you.

```
ViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Catalog"];
vc.itemId =0;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:Nil];
```